# Image Texture vs Color in 3D objects for Android OpenGL ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, glsl, render-to-texture

Is there any difference in terms of rendering overhead, if we simply use a color (e.g., green) or load a texture image file (e.g., green.png file) for a 3D object?

Shouldn't the **OpenGL ES** finally create a texture even for a ***colored*** object?

I am using Android API v8 along with the emulator and the goal is an actual Android phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would it finally create a texture for a colored object?

I can't speak to every conceivable implementation, but it seems to me that the uniform would be a much better solution. The uniform value is likely cached very locally in the datapath with quick access, versus a texture which has to interpolate the texture coordinates, retrieve the texture from vram, and sample it. I'm not sure how that could be as fast as just reading a couple floats from the uniform.